# Como criar um tipo de "DIV" em Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, div, xamarin-forms

Como faço para criar um componente parecido com uma `div` em `Xamarin Forms` ?
Preciso criar algo que dentro terá algumas `labels` com informações referentes ao endereço do usuário, e será exibido conforme a lista de endereços que ele tiver.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: OLa, o cidadão aqui fez um explicação sobre o uso de layouts e as diferenças com relação a tag "div" do HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813633/xamarin-forms-counterpart-to-div-in-xaml

Comment: Penso que o que `Grid` seja o que está procurando.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow cara, pensei em uma stackLayout, fiz aqui, só que não sei se dá pra criar os stacklayouts de acordo com a quantidade de registros que possui a lista. Sabe se é possível fazer dessa forma ?

Comment: Até dá mas se for criar vários `stacklayouts` não é recomendado por questão de performance. Veja aqui um exemplo da utilização com `Grid` https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/creating/